# How to get Preview of a shared file in MS Graph?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Im Using MS Graph Client and having a trouble of previewing Shared Items with me.

```
 ItemPreviewInfo preview = await graphClient.Me.Drive.Items[id].Preview().Request().PostAsync();
```

Gives no such file exists error as obvious cos its not in my drive. I know i need to access shared folder may be but  ""raphClient.Me.Drive.SharedWithMe...." does not give any item id specifications.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the shared drive item by calling :

```
DriveItem driveItem = await graphClient.Me.Drive.SharedWithMe().Request().GetAsync().FirstOrDefault();
```

Once you have retrieved the shared drive item, you can preview it by calling :

```
ItemPreviewInfo previewInfo = await client.Drives[sharedItem.RemoteItem.ParentReference.DriveId].Items[sharedItem.RemoteItem.Id].Preview().Request().PostAsync();
```

Since the shared items are from a different drive, you need to get the **RemoteItem-DriveId** for the shared drive and the **RemoteItem-Id** which identifies the **DriveItem** in the shared drive.

This is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/drive-sharedwithme?view=graph-rest-1.0#remarks)